# Find the common theme!

Tags: visual, knowledge

> **You have to find the common theme suggested from these pictures!**

[image]

Comment: Children's Movies/TV? then there's a toilet...

Comment: Is that black line near the toilet, *intentional*?

Comment: No, by accident :|

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think they are all

> First names of US Presidents

Reading left to right
First row

> **John** F Kennedy  - John is slang for toilet in the US 
> **Thomas** Jefferson  - Thomas the tank engine 
>  **Barack** Obama - sounds like Brock from Pokemon 
>  **George** Washington - George Weasley 
>  **Grover** Cleveland - Grover from Sesame Street.

Second row

> **Harry** S Truman  - Harry Potter 
>  **Donald** Trump - Donald Duck
>  **Warren** Harding - a rabbit warren 
>  **Theodore** Roosevelt - Theodore from the chipmunks.

Comment: Wow, that was fast. Good job! (P.S. the other one was **Warren** and that is a rabbit warren) :D

Comment: Ah thanks, yes, I thought it might be a famous fictional rabbit.

Comment: Congratulations: You have discovered yet _another_ way the US government can be compared to toilets

Comment: Grover is Sesame Street.

Comment: @WELZ Sorry, yes, you are correct. My bad.